# Recorrer hijos de hijos en un array de objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo un ID único que necesito encontrar en un objeto padre con muchos hijos de hijos.

El campo a encontrar sería *menuId*, ese identificador puede estar tanto en padre como en los hijos *children*, y si no se encuentra en primer objeto avanzar al segundo. Ya lo he intentando de muchas formas pero sigue sin funcionarme, es conveniente usar un método recursivo. Cabe aclarar que el objecto *children* tiene los mismos atributos que el método padre.

Más o menos cree algo así.

```
function handleHiera2(menuId, menuParent) {

    const response = [];

    let cont = 0;
    let key = 0;
    let value = 0;

    if (menuParent && menuParent.menuId != null) {

        if (menuParent.menuId == menuId) {
            response.push(menuParent);
        }
    }

    if (menuParent.children && menuParent.children.length > 0) {

        for ([key, value] of Object.entries(menuParent.children)) {

            if (value.menuId == menuId) {
                response.push(value);
            }
        }

        handleHiera2(menuId, menuParent.children);
    } else {
        cont += 1;
        const list = scope.listHierarchy[cont + 1];
        handleHiera2(menuId, list);
    }

}
}
```

Este es el objecto JSON que trae; eliminé varios child ya que no me deja subir mucho acá, pero la composición es parecida, la diferencia es que dentro de *children* pueden haber otros hijos

```
[
    {
        "menuId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
        "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
        "formId": null,
        "name": "Producción",
        "reportName": null,
        "workspace": null,
        "dashBoardName": null,
        "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-27T18:46:29.923",
        "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-27T18:46:29.923",
        "menuParentId": "f77da472-63c7-4318-a451-233664626df5",
        "isParent": true,
        "menuOrder": 9,
        "children": [
            {
                "menuId": "f9b8109b-ef77-4e23-9c6e-1be8484e3568",
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "formId": null,
                "name": "Anomalías Temperatura",
                "reportName": "EO MLT AnomaliasTemperatura v1.0",
                "workspace": "VU_Production",
                "dashBoardName": null,
                "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-28T15:09:58.44",
                "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-28T15:09:58.44",
                "menuParentId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
                "isParent": false,
                "menuOrder": 2,
                "children": [],
                "form": null,
                "icon": {
                    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                    "icon": "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",
                    "isParent": false,
                    "menus": []
                },
                "menuParent": null,
                "permissions": [],
                "permission": {
                    "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "view": false,
                    "edit": false,
                    "create": false,
                    "delete": false,
                    "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menu": null,
                    "user": null
                },
                "isActive": false,
                "reportFilters": [],
                "show": true
            },
            {
                "menuId": "b1704042-66f2-4b82-acf2-24d4b63431fc",
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "formId": null,
                "name": "Comparación de curvas de probabilidad - Rosa",
                "reportName": "EO-IACPO_CurvasProbabilidadRosa_V1.0",
                "workspace": "VU_Production",
                "dashBoardName": null,
                "creationUtcDate": "2021-02-01T17:00:59.193",
                "modificationUtcDate": "2021-02-01T17:00:59.193",
                "menuParentId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
                "isParent": false,
                "menuOrder": 3,
                "children": [],
                "form": null,
                "icon": {
                    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                    "icon": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAZ1JREFUeNrcVcFNw0AQjJH/uAPcAUkFCRUQpPxjf/gmrgBSQf58Ev95uIM4FWBXQKggpgKYRXPoZN3ZdzEvTlpZ3vPd7M7Orkej/7IC/eX29THG4wCLPe5oYGm9eClsH4St9wRWwXIPkGvYCmYFuTL4atiTI8AS9tn3UWjbQPrPGo1jPN5Iy17zT10iCR0jXql7bR8wEKlPRNcJATU+IBls7EBdrQWSs77OIGsqLu6gN9Oy2vYV3lYfiSp1DKomdd01QTRfBvcZ/rbvaDquqPoFwcGIlCi1bDz65EZoxB2SbYGsK5u6EhYuv2BqfPDclBk82Ogq2ICNnqbHiijz1ERXoNVg5tHppqVqU4Ky0joguxaCOODwnWVvS8qFkRmBUi8Jd6hITW4RzYQXT2BzTgBvENucEpAKACf2lKprdAmIrVFLSjhhZglHUPWXdM2pyh0beKeNouF04dI1L82QUaCMUr5ng/qpS2vWpSgNvrM0X1uymiDeBdQnExk1JU2NncgEwFqJECrpv2BI0VmDTc8/Jh2qrqxn/+fH9S3AAND3lQL1q8ymAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
                    "isParent": false,
                    "menus": []
                },
                "menuParent": null,
                "permissions": [],
                "permission": {
                    "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "view": false,
                    "edit": false,
                    "create": false,
                    "delete": false,
                    "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menu": null,
                    "user": null
                },
                "isActive": false,
                "reportFilters": [],
                "show": true
            },
           
        ],
        "form": null,
        "icon": {
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "icon": "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",
            "isParent": false,
            "menus": []
        },
        "menuParent": null,
        "permissions": [],
        "permission": {
            "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "view": false,
            "edit": false,
            "create": false,
            "delete": false,
            "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "menu": null,
            "user": null
        },
        "isActive": false,
        "reportFilters": [],
        "show": true,
        "$$hashKey": "object:394"
    },
    {
        "menuId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
        "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
        "formId": null,
        "name": "Supply Chain",
        "reportName": null,
        "workspace": null,
        "dashBoardName": null,
        "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:25:37.427",
        "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:25:37.427",
        "menuParentId": "b9557aa7-8cad-488a-abcd-ff24cb8cee6d",
        "isParent": true,
        "menuOrder": 8,
        "children": [
            {
                "menuId": "fa15d9d6-dd57-4f7f-80cc-5c1f0809b208",
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "formId": null,
                "name": "BSC Logística",
                "reportName": "BSC Logística - Val 2021",
                "workspace": "VU_SupplyChain",
                "dashBoardName": null,
                "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-25T14:17:13.327",
                "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-25T14:17:13.327",
                "menuParentId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
                "isParent": false,
                "menuOrder": 1,
                "children": [
                                {
                                "menuId": "c69d248f-3aa1-4f0f-9ad7-d0d740774bed",
                                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                                "formId": null,
                                "name": "Dashboard QU",
                                "reportName": "Dashboard QU 5-15",
                                "workspace": "VU_SupplyChain",
                                "dashBoardName": null,
                                "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:09:35.61",
                                "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:09:35.61",
                                "menuParentId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
                                "isParent": false,
                                "menuOrder": 2,
                                "children": [],
                                "form": null,
                                "icon": {
                                    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                                    "icon": "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",
                                    "isParent": false,
                                    "menus": []
                                },
                                "menuParent": null,
                                "permissions": [],
                                "permission": {
                                    "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                                    "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                                    "view": false,
                                    "edit": false,
                                    "create": false,
                                    "delete": false,
                                    "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                                    "menu": null,
                                    "user": null
                                },
                                "isActive": false,
                                "reportFilters": [],
                                "show": true
                            },
            
                ],
                "form": null,
                "icon": {
                    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                    "icon": "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",
                    "isParent": false,
                    "menus": []
                },
                "menuParent": null,
                "permissions": [],
                "permission": {
                    "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "view": false,
                    "edit": false,
                    "create": false,
                    "delete": false,
                    "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "menu": null,
                    "user": null
                },
                "isActive": false,
                "reportFilters": [],
                "show": true
            },

            
        ],
        "form": null,
        "icon": {
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "icon": "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",
            "isParent": false,
            "menus": []
        },
        "menuParent": null,
        "permissions": [],
        "permission": {
            "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "view": false,
            "edit": false,
            "create": false,
            "delete": false,
            "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "menu": null,
            "user": null
        },
        "isActive": false,
        "reportFilters": [],
        "show": true,
        "$$hashKey": "object:395"
    }
]
```

Lo que debe devolver es si encuentro dentro de un objeto hijo el resultado. Devolver todo el array completo que lo contiene para poder listarlo en un select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega el json para poder revisar la estructura y poder ver mejor la solución

Comment: @Charls listo ya agregué el json con una breve descripción

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo de que resultado esperas dado un argumento x a la función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro aún si esto es lo que necesitas, pero básicamente este código te devuelve como valor el elemento cuyo `menuId` es el buscado, sino encuentra nada retorna `undefined`

```js
const data = [
{
    "menuId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
    "formId": null,
    "name": "Producción",
    "reportName": null,
    "workspace": null,
    "dashBoardName": null,
    "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-27T18:46:29.923",
    "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-27T18:46:29.923",
    "menuParentId": "f77da472-63c7-4318-a451-233664626df5",
    "isParent": true,
    "menuOrder": 9,
    "children": [
        {
            "menuId": "f9b8109b-ef77-4e23-9c6e-1be8484e3568",
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "formId": null,
            "name": "Anomalías Temperatura",
            "reportName": "EO MLT AnomaliasTemperatura v1.0",
            "workspace": "VU_Production",
            "dashBoardName": null,
            "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-28T15:09:58.44",
            "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-28T15:09:58.44",
            "menuParentId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
            "isParent": false,
            "menuOrder": 2,
            "children": [],
            "form": null,
            "icon": {
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "icon": "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",
                "isParent": false,
                "menus": []
            },
            "menuParent": null,
            "permissions": [],
            "permission": {
                "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "view": false,
                "edit": false,
                "create": false,
                "delete": false,
                "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menu": null,
                "user": null
            },
            "isActive": false,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "show": true
        },
        {
            "menuId": "b1704042-66f2-4b82-acf2-24d4b63431fc",
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "formId": null,
            "name": "Comparación de curvas de probabilidad - Rosa",
            "reportName": "EO-IACPO_CurvasProbabilidadRosa_V1.0",
            "workspace": "VU_Production",
            "dashBoardName": null,
            "creationUtcDate": "2021-02-01T17:00:59.193",
            "modificationUtcDate": "2021-02-01T17:00:59.193",
            "menuParentId": "1ca36ec2-31cf-4e3b-b499-59315f953a39",
            "isParent": false,
            "menuOrder": 3,
            "children": [],
            "form": null,
            "icon": {
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "icon": "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",
                "isParent": false,
                "menus": []
            },
            "menuParent": null,
            "permissions": [],
            "permission": {
                "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "view": false,
                "edit": false,
                "create": false,
                "delete": false,
                "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menu": null,
                "user": null
            },
            "isActive": false,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "show": true
        },

    ],
    "form": null,
    "icon": {
        "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
        "icon": "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",
        "isParent": false,
        "menus": []
    },
    "menuParent": null,
    "permissions": [],
    "permission": {
        "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "view": false,
        "edit": false,
        "create": false,
        "delete": false,
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "menu": null,
        "user": null
    },
    "isActive": false,
    "reportFilters": [],
    "show": true,
    "$$hashKey": "object:394"
},
{
    "menuId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
    "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
    "formId": null,
    "name": "Supply Chain",
    "reportName": null,
    "workspace": null,
    "dashBoardName": null,
    "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:25:37.427",
    "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:25:37.427",
    "menuParentId": "b9557aa7-8cad-488a-abcd-ff24cb8cee6d",
    "isParent": true,
    "menuOrder": 8,
    "children": [
        {
            "menuId": "fa15d9d6-dd57-4f7f-80cc-5c1f0809b208",
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "formId": null,
            "name": "BSC Logística",
            "reportName": "BSC Logística - Val 2021",
            "workspace": "VU_SupplyChain",
            "dashBoardName": null,
            "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-25T14:17:13.327",
            "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-25T14:17:13.327",
            "menuParentId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
            "isParent": false,
            "menuOrder": 1,
            "children": [],
            "form": null,
            "icon": {
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "icon": "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",
                "isParent": false,
                "menus": []
            },
            "menuParent": null,
            "permissions": [],
            "permission": {
                "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "view": false,
                "edit": false,
                "create": false,
                "delete": false,
                "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menu": null,
                "user": null
            },
            "isActive": false,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "show": true
        },
        {
            "menuId": "c69d248f-3aa1-4f0f-9ad7-d0d740774bed",
            "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
            "formId": null,
            "name": "Dashboard QU",
            "reportName": "Dashboard QU 5-15",
            "workspace": "VU_SupplyChain",
            "dashBoardName": null,
            "creationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:09:35.61",
            "modificationUtcDate": "2021-01-20T14:09:35.61",
            "menuParentId": "cac1dbd6-012b-46cc-805a-f28f43bcbe96",
            "isParent": false,
            "menuOrder": 2,
            "children": [],
            "form": null,
            "icon": {
                "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
                "icon": "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",
                "isParent": false,
                "menus": []
            },
            "menuParent": null,
            "permissions": [],
            "permission": {
                "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "view": false,
                "edit": false,
                "create": false,
                "delete": false,
                "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "menu": null,
                "user": null
            },
            "isActive": false,
            "reportFilters": [],
            "show": true
        },

    ],
    "form": null,
    "icon": {
        "iconId": "7fde6368-7686-4de8-86b2-e667c7767ec0",
        "icon": "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",
        "isParent": false,
        "menus": []
    },
    "menuParent": null,
    "permissions": [],
    "permission": {
        "permissionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "menuId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "view": false,
        "edit": false,
        "create": false,
        "delete": false,
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "menu": null,
        "user": null
    },
    "isActive": false,
    "reportFilters": [],
    "show": true,
    "$$hashKey": "object:395"
}
]

function searchMenuId(id, data) {
if (data.menuId && data.menuId === id) {
    return data;
}

if (data.children && data.children.length) {
    let res;
    data.children.find(children => {
        res = searchMenuId(id, children);

        return res;
    });

    if (res) {
        return res;
    }
}
}

let itemMatch;

data.find((item) => {
itemMatch = searchMenuId('c69d248f-3aa1-4f0f-9ad7-d0d740774bed', item);

return itemMatch;
})

console.log({ itemMatch });
```

Comment: Daniel dios te pague, te queria preguntar, si quiero devolver por ejemplo.Lo que debe devolver es si encuentro dentro de un objecto hijo el resultado. Devolver todo el array completo que lo contiene para poder listarlo en un select

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con todo el "Array completo"?

Comment: Es decir, encontré el valor dos niveles abajo en el campo children. Ahora tengo que devolver la lista un nivel mas arriba. padre -> children (devolver todo el array) -> children (aca encontre el valor)

Comment: Vale entiendo, ¿y qué debería pasar si encuentras el valor en un nodo padre?

Comment: si lo encuentra en valor padre, devolver todos los padres, asi sea sin hijos no importa